# Registered BroadCast Receiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way to "Scan" All Apps for registered BroadCastReceiver for a specific Action & get the class Name, for example Action Screen On/Off(if root is needed no problems) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the desired `Intent`. Use [`PackageManager` and `queryBroadcastReceivers()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to find out who all responds to that `Intent`, at least for manifest-registered receivers. I do not know if `PackageManager` returns receivers registered via `registerReceiver()`, and since that's the only type of receiver that works with `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`, you might not be able to get data for those specific actions.

Comment: Thanks, & then, how to get the class Name of those Package ? i guess Root is needed because since LolliPop we can not get the class name anymore of the running Task, but is there a way to get it(Receiver Class Name) ? my goal finally is to disable those Receiver temporary.

Comment: @SmokCol: "how to get the class Name of those Package ?" -- you get that via the `ResolveInfo` objects that are returned by `queryBroadcastReceivers()`. "my goal finally is to disable those Receiver temporary" -- *that* is not possible, except with a custom ROM or possibly a rooted device.